# selectOneMenu com converter não funciona

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Possuo um selectOneMenu onde estou populando com os dados do banco de dados mas o mesmo está vindo com o endereço de memória (ver imagem), e não o valor que quero.

Tentei resolver usando o exemplo desse vídeo https://youtu.be/3XGwUTPJ9x8?list=PL_GwGUsBlNyfI0W3ggfffhBdJUqB4981Z além de perguntas similares feitas em fóruns e outras fontes de pesquisa, mas sem sucesso e não sei onde estou errando.

Abaixo segue o código do meu selectOneMenu e do converter.

Meu selectOneMenu:

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Veiculo: " />
 <p:selectOneMenu id="selectVeiculo" filter="true"
  value="#{manutencaoBean.manutencao.veiculo}"
  converter="veiculoConverter">
  <f:selectItems 
   value="#{manutencaoBean.veiculo}" var="veiculo"
   itemValue="#{veiculo}" itemLabel="#{veiculoBean.veiculo.placa}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Meu converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value="veiculoConverter", forClass = Veiculo.class) 
public class VeiculoConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) { 
    if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        Integer codigo = Integer.valueOf(value); 
        try {
            VeiculoRN veiculoRN = new VeiculoRN();
            return veiculoRN.carregar(codigo); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConverterException("Não foi possível encontrar a categoria de código " 
                + value + ". " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) { 
    if (value != null) {
        Veiculo veiculo = (Veiculo) value; 
        return veiculo.getCodigo_veiculo().toString();  }
    return "";
}
}
```

Imagem com o erro apresentado:
[image: Campo da tela de cadastro com erro]

Classe Veículo:

```
@Entity
public class Veiculo implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5574236691480093866L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer codigo_veiculo;
private String placa;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="veiculo", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Manutencao> manutencao;
//gets sets e hashcode e equals
```

Classe Manutencao:

```
@Entity
public class Manutencao implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 9031330110535169652L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer cod_manutencao;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_veiculo")
private Veiculo veiculo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="manutencao", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ItensManutencao> itensManutencao;
//gets sets e hashcode e equals
```

Classe ManutencaoBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "manutencaoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ManutencaoBean {
private Manutencao manutencao = new Manutencao();
private List<Manutencao> lista;
private List<Veiculo> veiculo;
private List<ItensManutencao> itensManutencao;

public String novo() {
    this.manutencao = new Manutencao();
    return "/publico/manutencao";
}

public String salvar() {
    ManutencaoRN manutencaoRN = new ManutencaoRN();
    manutencaoRN.salvar(this.manutencao);
    return null;
}

public List<Manutencao> getLista() {
    if (this.lista == null) {
        ManutencaoRN manutencaoRN = new ManutencaoRN();
        this.lista = manutencaoRN.listar();
    }
    return this.lista;
}

public List<Veiculo> getVeiculo() {
    this.veiculo = new ArrayList<Veiculo>();
    VeiculoRN veiculoRN = new VeiculoRN();
    this.veiculo = veiculoRN.listar();

    return veiculo;
}

public List<ItensManutencao> getItensManutencao() {
    this.itensManutencao = new ArrayList<ItensManutencao>();
    ItensManutencaoRN itensManutencaoRN = new ItensManutencaoRN();
    this.itensManutencao = itensManutencaoRN.listar();

    return itensManutencao;
}

//gets sets
```

Classe ItensManutencao:

```
@Entity
public class ItensManutencao implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8496201153212695359L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer cod_item_manutencao;
private String descricao;
private Integer quantidade;
private Float valorUnitario;
private Float total;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_manutencao")
private Manutencao manutencao;
// gets sets hashcode e equals
```

Classe ItensManutencaoBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "itensManutencaoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ItensManutencaoBean {
private ItensManutencao itensManutencao = new ItensManutencao();
private Manutencao manutencao = new Manutencao();
private List<ItensManutencao> lista;

public String novo() {
    this.itensManutencao = new ItensManutencao();
    return "/publico/itensmanutencao";
}

public String salvar() {
    ManutencaoRN manutencaoRN = new ManutencaoRN();
    manutencaoRN.salvar(this.manutencao);

    ItensManutencaoRN itensManutencaoRN = new ItensManutencaoRN();
    itensManutencaoRN.salvar(this.itensManutencao);
    return null;
}

public String excluir() {
    ManutencaoRN manutencaoRN = new ManutencaoRN();
    manutencaoRN.salvar(this.manutencao);

    ItensManutencaoRN itensManutencaoRN = new ItensManutencaoRN();
    itensManutencaoRN.excluir(this.itensManutencao);
    this.lista = null;
    return null;
}

public List<ItensManutencao> getLista() {
    if (this.lista == null) {
        ItensManutencaoRN itensManutencaoRN = new ItensManutencaoRN();
        this.lista = itensManutencaoRN.listar();
    }
    return this.lista;
}
//gets e sets
```

[image: Tela de cadastro de manutenção e itens de manutenção]

O que estou tentando fazer agora é adicionar os itens de manutenção (classe ItensManutencao) e as demais informações (parte superior na imagem, que corresponde a classe Manutencao).

Ao tentar adicionar um item, o mesmo não está salvando, acredito que como existe um relacionamento entre as tabelas, a tabela Manutencao ainda não possui um cod_manutencao.

Não sei como devo fazer para ir adicionando os itens referentes a esse formulário de manutenção e associar esses itens que foram adicionados com essa manutenção.

Comment: Coloca sua entidade Veiculo na pergunta

Comment: @ErickLuz Adicionei as classes Veiculo, Manutencao e ManutencaoBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc está usando a variável `manutencaoBean.veiculo` como lista de origem e valor de saída. Tenta usar a `manutencaoBean.manutencao.veiculo` para a saída (exemplo abaixo).

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Veiculo: " />
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectVeiculo" filter="true"
 value="#{manutencaoBean.manutencao.veiculo}" converter="veiculoConverter">
 <f:selectItems value="#{manutencaoBean.veiculo}" var="veiculo"
  itemValue="#{veiculo}" itemLabel="#{veiculo.placa}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Olá Marcus, fiz a alteração sugeria e agora está dando o erro `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity`.

Comment: Como vc está salvando a entidade?

Comment: Acredito que está ocorrendo esse erro porque eu criei uma classe chamada ItensManutencao e a classe Manutencao possui um relacionamento OneToMany com essa classe. 
Os itens não estão salvando no banco, e acredito que é porque não sei como pegar o código de Manutencao no momento de salvar. 
Vou editar a pergunta colocando a imagem e essas outras classes para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: Marcus, editei a pergunta adicionando a classe ItensManutencao e o que adicionei na classe Manutencao e ManutencaoBean, e tentei explicar o que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc está criando uma manutenção e tem diversos itens de manutencão. Acho que não deveria ter 2 beans gerenciando isso. Somente o ManutencaoBean cuidaria de tudo. Se vc quer que os itens de manutenção sejam persistidos junto com a manutenção, sugiro alterar o Manutencao: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="manutencao", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` `private List<ItensManutencao> itensManutencao;`

Comment: Marcus, não entendi o que que devo fazer, como só o ManutencaoBean que deve cuidar disso. Que alterações devo fazer?
Os atributos que estão em ItensManutencao devem estar em Manutencao?

Comment: Eu entendi que esse é um formulário de manutenção. Cada manutenção tem diversos itens de manutenção. Nesse caso, vc tem somente um formulário para editar a entidade Manutencao, juntamente com seus itens. Acho que o mais indicado é que bean controle apenas essa entidade e os itens de manutenção sejam inseridos via cascade, em um relacionamento One-To-Many. Sugiro consultar esse link https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema da exibição do valor vindo do banco de dados.
Fiz assim no meu selectOneMenu:

```html
<h:outputLabel value="Veiculo: " />
 <p:selectOneMenu id="selectVeiculo" filter="true"
  value="#{manutencaoBean.veiculo}" converter="veiculoConverter">
  <f:selectItems value="#{manutencaoBean.veiculo}" var="veiculo"
   itemValue="#{veiculo}" itemLabel="#{veiculo.placa}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Mas agora estou com outro problema. Ao tentar salvar está dando o erro:

> javax.el.ELException: /publico/manutencao.xhtml @11,66 value="#{manutencaoBean.veiculo}": Cannot convert [br.com.oficina.veiculo.Veiculo@f23f4348] of type [class br.com.oficina.veiculo.Veiculo] to [interface java.util.List]

Procurei formas de tentar resolver esse outro problema e as soluções que tentei ainda não resolveram esse problema.